# How to write the € symbol into a file, when using Package [utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: unicode, characters, write

With the following MWE, I can write the € symbol into the file euro.txt

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile="euro.txt"

\begin{document}
Write Euro symbol into a file
\immediate\write\tempfile{10 €}%
\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\end{document}
```

My problem is that I use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, and with this encoding, the symbol € produces a bug. What could i do ?

```
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Answer (score 11):

Writing out Unicode characters is a pain. It mostly depends on what you want that it is written in the file.

If you can, the simplest way out is

```
\immediate\write\tempfile{10\unexpanded{€}}
```

but this may not be what you're looking for. So let's try a different strategy.

First of all you need an "immediate" version of `\protected@write`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\protected@iwrite[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\thepage\relax
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write #1{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Then this will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\protected@iwrite[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\thepage\relax
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write #1{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile="euro.txt"

\begin{document}
Write Euro symbol into a file and in the document: €
\makeatletter
\protected@iwrite\tempfile{}{10€}%
\makeatother
\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\end{document}
```

This will write

```
10\IeC {\texteuro }
```

which still may not be what you need.

If you want a literal € character, you can do in this way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\makeatletter
\newunicodechar{€}{\ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect\unexpanded{€}\else\texteuro\fi}

\newcommand\protected@iwrite[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\thepage\relax
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write #1{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Write Euro symbol into a file and in the document: €
\makeatletter
\protected@iwrite\tempfile{}{10€}%
\makeatother
\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\end{document}
```

This will write

```
10€
```

Notice however that you need `\usepackage{textcomp}` to give a meaning to `€`.