# \write18 encoding

Tags: input-encodings, shell-escape, getmap

I wrote a `bash` script [osmimage](http://jklatex.square7.de/2014/05/17/osmimage-sh-bash-script/) ([source for tests](http://jklatex.square7.de//download/osmimage)), that downloads a map given by an address. I want to write a package that calls this script with `\write18`, but there are a few problems.

The following example works with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\loc{Bergheimer Straße 110A, 69115 Heidelberg, Germany}
%\def\loc{Rathausmarkt 1, 20095 Hamburg, Deutschland}
\newcommand*\getmap%
{%
  %\immediate\write18{osmimage -l "\loc"}
  \immediate\write18{osmimage -l "\unexpanded\expandafter{\loc}"}
}%
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
Did you ever wanted to visit the Dante e.V. office? Here we go:

\getmap
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{osmimage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Code edited** after Ulrike's comment. Still a problem with `pdflatex` and other encoding than `utf-8`!

[image: map wuth Dante e.V. office]

If i run this file with `pdflatex` (with `inputenc` and `fontenc`) the transfer of the address no longer works. Without `inputenc` or `fontenc` i get all kinds of strange output in the URL (see log).

If i use an ASCII-only address like the Hamburg town hall, it also works with `pdflatex`!

[image: map Hamburg town hall]

So there seems to be some kind of encoding problem as the script expects `UTF-8` or maybe url-encoding.

Any idea? It wouldn't be very nice to limit the package to <del>`lualatex` or maybe `xelatex` (not tested yet)</del> `utf-8` encoding

Comment: Try `\immediate\write18{osmimage -l "\unexpanded\expandafter{\loc}"}`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75958/2388

Comment: Yes, this works with `pdflatex` and `utf8` encoding. There are still encoding problems, when using `latin1` instead. Anyway, thank you very much, Mrs.(!!!) Fischer ;-)

Comment: @Josef I guess the script expects the address in UTF-8 encoding. Unless you modify it to interpret Latin-1, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package [`stringenc`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/stringenc.pdf) can convert the address string from `latin1` to `utf-8`, needed by `osmimage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stringenc}
\def\loc{Bergheimer StraXe 110A, 69115 Heidelberg, Germany}
%\def\loc{Rathausmarkt 1, 20095 Hamburg, Deutschland}
\newcommand*\getmap{%
  \StringEncodingConvert{\locstring}{%
    \detokenize\expandafter{\loc}%
  }{latin1}{utf-8}%
  \StringEncodingSuccessFailure{% success
  }{% failure
    \errmessage{Converting to UTF-8 failed}%
  }%
  \immediate\write18{osmimage -l "\locstring"}
}%
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
Did you ever wanted to visit the Dante e.V. office? Here we go:

\getmap
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{osmimage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]