# Why is my float missing with endfloat?

Tags: endfloat

When using `\processdelayedfloats` with the `endfloat` package, a float may go missing, such as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    This float will be missing!
\end{figure}

Text before all floats.

\processdelayedfloats

Text after all floats.

\end{document}
```

Is this known and/or intended?

Comment: That is a bug in (the new version of) endfloat. It basically uses `\immediate \protected@write` to write the floats to the external file, but this doesn't make sense as the `\immediate` has no effect on the `\protected@write`.  As `\processdelayedfloats` closes the file also with `\immediate` the file is closed before the floats have been written.

Comment: egreg has an immediate protected write here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75951/how-to-write-the-%e2%82%ac-symbol-into-a-file-when-using-package-utf8inputenc

Comment: Known bug: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/endfloat/issues/5 (I will fix it in the next version of `endfloat`.)